# Пользователь по команде "p" может узнать владельца документа по его номеру

Tags: python, функции

Дано:

```
documents = [{'type': 'passport', 'number': '2207 876234', 'name': 'Василий Гупкин'}, {'type': 'invoice', 'number': '11-2', 'name': 'Геннадий Покемонов'}, {'type': 'insurance', 'number': '10006', 'name': 'Аристарх Павлов'}]

directories = {'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'], '2': ['10006'], '3': []}
```

Мой код:

```
def p():
    num = input("Введите номер документа:")
    for dic in documents:
        for key,value in dic.items():
            if key == "number" and value == num:
                print(dic["name"])
            elif key == "number" and value != num:
                print("Документ не найден в базе")
                                
p()
```

Выводит:

```
Введите номер документа:10006
Документ не найден в базе
Документ не найден в базе
Аристарх Павлов
```

Как сделать, чтоб выводило только имя пользователя, либо (если нет такого номера) только фразу "Документ не найден в базе"

Answer (score 1):

Если номер документа в базе ТОЛЬКО один раз встречается

```
def p():
    num = input("Введите номер документа:")
    for dic in documents:
        if "number" in dic.keys() and dic["number"] == num:
            print(dic["name"])
            break
    else:
        print("Документ не найден в базе")
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
def p():
    num = input("Введите номер документа:")
    for dic in documents:
        found = False

        for key, value in dic.items():
            if key == "number" and value == num:
                print(dic["name"])
                found = True
                break

        if not found:
            print("Документ не найден в базе")
                                
p()
```

Answer (score 0):

Будет работать и с несколькими документами на 1 персону

```
def p():
    found = False
    num = input("Введите номер документа:")
    for dic in documents:
        if "number" in dic.keys() and dic["number"] == num:
            print(dic["name"])
            found = True

    if not found:
        print("Документ не найден в базе")

p()
```

Answer (score 0):

Выведите последние две строчки из цикла:

```
elif key == "number" and value != num:
 print("Документ не найден в базе")
```

Тогда фразы "Документ не найден в базе" при переборе не будут вылезать